# Should I stir fry all my vegetables at the same time or do them one at time?

Tags: vegetables, stir-fry

I want to stir fry broccolis, onions, mushrooms, and carrots. Should I do them all at the same time or separately because they might have different cooking time?

Comment: The correct answer is 'neither'...please see the answer to the question [What's the best order to add ingredients to a stir fry](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3420/6279).

Comment: When you say 'all at the same time', are you talking about having them all in the wok at the same time, even though they might be added in stages?  I prefer this method, but it requires having a large enough vessel and a high enough heat output for the amount that you're cooking

Comment: 'all at the same time' i mean by adding all of the ingredients at the beginning.

Comment: The listed link is fine answer IMO, to summarize though, usually don't add all at one time.  Start with spices and aromatics the go from long cooking times to short then serve.